# Generalized objects and category of elements

Tags: category-theory

I read on Awodey's book that a category can always be thought as a concrete category, in the sense that it is isomorphic to a subcategory of $\mathsf{Set}$. I imagine that this has to do with Yoneda's embedding, but I'm not sure how.

Let $\mathsf C$ be a small category, and denote by $\sf Cat$ the category of small  categories. One can construct a (not strictly commutative) triangle using the Yoneda embedding $\operatorname y:\sf C\to Set^{C^{op}}$, the functor $\int  :\sf Set^{C^{op}}\to Cat$ sending a presheaf to its category of elements, and the functor $\sf C/: C\to Cat$, defined as $c\mapsto \mathsf C/c$ on the objects. Then, denoting with $\circ$ the composition of functors for clarity, there is a natural isomorphism  $\Psi:\int \circ \operatorname y\cong\mathsf C/:\sf C\to Cat$.

Let $\operatorname {ob}:\sf Cat \to Set$ be the functor sending a (small) category to its set of objects. The composites $\operatorname{ob}\circ\int \circ \operatorname y$ and $\operatorname{ob}\circ\ \mathsf C/:\sf C\to Set$ are naturally isomorphic, via $\operatorname {ob}\circ \Psi$, and they are faithful: given $f:c\to c'$ in $\sf C$, the induced functor $\mathsf C/c\to \mathsf C/c'$ is univocally determined by the condition that sends $\operatorname {id}_c$ to $f$, and one can reason similarly for $\operatorname{ob}\circ\int \circ \operatorname y$.

Hence we obtained in two ways a faithful functor $\iota:\sf C\to Set$, that is, $\sf C$ is isomorphic to a subcategory of $\sf Set$; also, the elements of $\iota(c)$ are exactly the  generalized objects  of $c$. Do you agree? If $\sf C$ is assumed to be just locally small,  do the same result hold replacing $\sf Cat$ with the category of locally small categories and the codomain of $\operatorname {ob}$ with the category of classes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathrm{ob}$ is certainly not faithful; you are claiming that different functors must act differently on objects.

Comment: Maybe for questions of smallness (which I don't know much about)? Theorem 1.6 of Awodey's book says exactly that any small category is isomorphic to a concrete one, and in fact I assumed $\sf C$ small.

Comment: [The category hTop, where the objects are topological spaces and the morphisms are homotopy classes of continuous functions, is an example of a category that is not concretizable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category#Counter-examples)

Comment: Oh the same article says all small categories are concretizable, so you're trying to prove a true statement.

Comment: Related: every "decently interesting" homotopy category is not concrete: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00303 ; every category is a quotient of a concrete category  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404971900041